# Как эмулировать нажатие на кнопку на сайте?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Пишу мобильное приложение для сайта у которого нет своего API. Надо эмулировать нажатие на кнопку. Не понимаю, что показывают снифферы http. Как отправлять запрос с помощью JSOUP.Может есть какой-то пример?

Comment: дайте ссылку на страницу, на которой надо нажать кнопку.

Comment: http://auto-aksrzn.ru/detskie-kresla/siger/

кнопка в корзину или купить

Comment: и какую кнопку вы хотите нажать?

Comment: нажать на кнопку В корзину

Comment: тогда вам надо использовать пункт 2 из ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от ожидаемого результата и реализации "кнопки на сайте".

1. Как правило, после нажатия должны возникнуть некоторые запросы к серверу. Посмотрите в консоль браузера какие идут HTTP-запросы и уже их вызывайте через JSOUP (или что-нибудь еще);
2. Нажатие на кнопку вызывает JavaScript-обработчики, алгоритм которых по каким-либо причинам сложно или не хотите воспроизвести у себя в приложении. Тогда вам потребуется применение эмулятора браузера (например [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)). Это будет более ресурсоемко, но при изменениии скриптов на сайте вам не потребуется вносить изменения в приложение (Если конечно кнопку не переверстают)